# CropImage Library is not working in Fragments

Tags: android

`CropImage` Library is working fine in `Activity` but it is not working in `Fragments`. It is not getting the image in `Fragments`.

I changed context from `MainActivity.this` to `getActivity()` but it is not working.

My code:

```
private void getImage() {
 CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == galleryPic && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri image = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(image).setAspectRatio(1, 1).start(getContext(), this);
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            File fileImage = new File(resultUri.getPath());
            // compressImage method will compress the image.
            byte[] byteImageCompress = compressImage(fileImage);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImageCompress, 0, byteImageCompress.length);
                            imageViewChairman.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get image using CropImage Library in Fragments?

Comment: have you checked from https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/479? There's an issue about this in https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/518

Answer (score 4):

I changed `getActivity()` to `(getContext(), this)` and it works for me.

Before:

```
CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(getActivity());
```

After:

```
CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(getContext(), this);
```

Comment: .start(getContext(), this); not working in fragment

Answer (score 0):

I prefer create a App class and extend Aplication, later add manifest aplication name as App class path. And create a instance methot like singleton in the App class. I think you can use everywhere `App.getInstance().getApplicationContext`

```
    public class App extends Application {
    
        public static App instance = null;
    
        public static App getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new App();
            }
            return instance;
        }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

**manifest file**

```
<application
            android:name=".application.App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen">
        <activity.......
```

sorry for my bad english :/